# How to import .eml files into Mail?

Tags: mail.app, email, macos

I'm using `readpst` to extract emails from a bunch of old outlook `.PST` files.

It does a great job of pulling out all the emails `.EML` files, with attachments included.

But how do I bring these into Apple Mail?

Any of the "Import..." options create a separate mailbox for **each message.**

I want to be able to import groups of messages into a particular mailbox.

(I know that `readpst` can also generate `mbox` files, which Apple Mail handles OK, but slowly; but this is not what I want to do.)

Comment: I've heard some folks have had success exporting .eml files in .mbox format with Microsoft Outlook|Office 2011.

Comment: eml or emlx files

Comment: Have you tried just to drag and drop the .eml files into Apple Mail ??

Comment: @ReneLarsen yes, that was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 19):

If you put the exported e-mails (*.eml files) into a folder structure, then just select the outer folder as the import folder.

The test import I just did is like below:

1. Select "Apple Mail" as the "Import data from":

[image]

2. Select the outer (root) folder of the e-mails to import:

[image]

3. Confirm the selection:

[image]

4. The imported .eml e-mails is now in an 'import' mailbox (only one mailbox) with the same folder structure as the folder the import came from:

[image]

Now you can move all or selected e-mails from the import folder to the mailbox of choice. When all e-mails has been moved, just delete the 'import' mailbox.

Comment: Thanks, that works ... but did you notice that nearly all messages have an unopenable attachment called "Mail Atttachment"? Or is that just me? Might be because of `readpst`

Comment: I don't have any problems with the attachments - but I also only did a small test, where I exported some e-mails (drag'n'drop) - and the imported them again - two of them had attachments.

Comment: I wish I had found this answer before all my failed attempts to convert a folder full of .eml files to one .mbox file. Since the files were exported from Windows Vista Mail, it never occurred to me that "Apple Mail" was the option I should select.

Comment: For some reason, when I try this, each .eml gets its own folder, but both are at the same level in the same folder in the filesystem.

Comment: @AdamGrant Me, too, unfotunately. Did you figure out a way to avoid this?

Comment: @mdomino, @AdamGrant: If you rename the parent directory to have a `.mbox` extension (so, for example, the structure ends up looking like: `import.mbox/message1.eml`, `import.mbox/message2.eml`), then the current version of Mail seems to properly import all of the messages into a single folder (rather than each EML file getting its own folder).

Comment: The only problem with this for me is that for emails with attachments the paperclip icon doesn't show where the emails are listed. It still shows on the email itself and the attachment will still open.

Comment: This does not work in Big Sur.

Comment: @A.G. I just tried, and it still worked for me in Big Sur - so I don't know what your issue could be. All the steps shown are still the same in Big Sur - at least for me.

Comment: This worked for me. But it was critical to adopt @Nick M's method. Further, with Mail 16.0 it is not necessary to add the parent folder if the original folder is given the .mbox extension.